# Grails nested URL mappings yields to null

Tags: grails, grails-rest-api

I am trying make use of the nested URL as documented in the [RestFul URLs section](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#restfulMappings)

It seems that the nested resource is not receiving a reference to the object the url is deriving from.
URLmapping:

```
"/books"(resources: 'book') {
    "/reviews"(resources: "review")
}
```

...

```
@Resource(uri = '/books', formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Book{
    static hasMany = [reviews: Review]
}
```

...

```
@Resource(uri = '/reviews', formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Review{
    static belongsTo = [book: Book]
...
    static constraints = {
        book nullable: false
    }
}
```

The error is a 422 pointing to
Grails default.null.message
{
"message": "Die Eigenschaft [book] des Typs [class core.Review] darf nicht null sein",
...
}
}

Is this a bug!?
If not, how to properly make use of Nested URLs for Rest Resources in Grails
(tested: Grails 4.0.3)

**Update:**
Request is being sent to:

POST $domain/books/1/reviews

```
{
    "description":"amazing book"
}
```

adding a `"book":1` in JSOn will create the review just fine. But that is not the point of using nested URL isn't it?

Comment: Which URL are you sending the request to, which HTTP method are you using, and if the request contains a body, what is in the body of the request?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Updating the question with the info requested

Comment: Are `description` and `book` (the `book` property is added as a result of the `belongsTo`) the only persistent property in the `Review` class?

Comment: yes
There is nothing else in review; keeping it simple

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Simple project -> https://github.com/abrahaj/grails403rest

Comment: Retrieving a nested resource (GET /books/1/reviews) works. 
Seems the issue is only on the creation. Seems a bug?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Should I report this as a bug?